# @BatchSize do not work - Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

We have a **Parent** table with **OneToMany** mapping with a **Child** table as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_DETAIL")
public class ParentVO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parentSeqGen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="parentSeqGen", sequenceName="PARENT_SEQ",  allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
private Long parentId; 
.............
................

@OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
private Set<ChildVO> childLists;

......................

}
```

and a **Child** table as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_CHILD_MAPPING")
public class ChildVO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "childSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="childSeq", sequenceName="CHILD_SEQ",  allocationSize = 1)  
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

.............

}
```

Now when we update the Parent object we need the child table to be updated too. For this we kept CascadeType.All in OneToMany annotation.

We had 3 Childs to update. The Child table is getting updated but I can see in console there are 3 Inserts followed by 3 update for n Childs.

I read somewhere the updates (on foreign keys) can be avoided by providing **mappedBy** attribute. We have unidirectional relationship, so is there any alternative for mappedBy? Or I will have to make the relationship bi-directional only.

But I guess the BatchSize should work. It should be 3 inserts in one go as batchsize is 10, correct?

Have also mentioned BatchSize in hibernate properties xml.

```
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
```

We are using HibernateTemplate update method (Old application) as below.

```
public void update(IBaseVO vo) {
    HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    ht.update(vo);
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, BatchSize works only for select operations.

Comment: Check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-batch-insert-and-update).

Comment: Is it the correct behavior in hibernate or I can reduce the number of insert calls? Please update.